# Powershell: Parse a structured text file and save to .CSV

Tags: parsing, powershell, text, csv

I'm very new to Powershell.  Only have been using it for about 2 weeks.

I have a file that is structured like this:

```
Service name: WSDL 
Service ID: 14234321885 
Service resolution path: /gman/wsdlUpdte 
Serivce endpoints: 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Service name: DataService 
Service ID: 419434324305 
Service resolution path: /widgetDate_serv/WidgetDateServ 
Serivce endpoints:  
http://servername.company.com:1012/widgetDate_serv/WidgetDateServ
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Service name: SearchService 
Service ID: 393234543546 
Service resolution path: /ProxyServices/SearchService 
Serivce endpoints:  
http://servername.company.com:13010/Services/SearchService_5_0
http://servername2.company.com:13010/Services/SearchService_5_0
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Service name: Worker 
Service ID: 14187898547 
Service resolution path: /ProxyServices/Worker 
Serivce endpoints:  
http://servername.company.com:131009/Services/Worker/v9
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'd like to parse the file and have Service name, Service ID, Service Resolution Path and Service Endpoints (which sometimes contain multiple or no values) in individual columms (CSV).

Beyond using Get-Content and looping through the file, I have no idea even where to start.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

1. Read the file content as one string
2. Split it by 81 hyphens
3. Split each splited item on  the colon char and take the last array item
4. Create new object for each item

   ```
   $pattern = '-'*81  
   $content = Get-Content D:\Scripts\Temp\p.txt | Out-String
   $content.Split($pattern,[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) | Where-Object {$_ -match '\S'} | ForEach-Object {

   $item = $_ -split "\s+`n" | Where-Object {$_}

       New-Object PSobject -Property @{
           Name=$item[0].Split(':')[-1].Trim()
           Id = $item[1].Split(':')[-1].Trim()
           ResolutionPath=$item[2].Split(':')[-1].Trim()
           Endpoints=$item[4..($item.Count)]
       } | Select-Object Name,Id,ResolutionPath,Endpoints
   }
   ```

Comment: you have to 'hardcode' fields, and don't take care of multiple urls.

Comment: Thanks Shay,
I needed to make a couple changes to fix some error messages, but it works great now when outputting to the console.  When I add "| export-csv test.csv" The last object (Endpoints) displays as "System.Object[]" in the actual file.  I'm assuming that something needs to be done to that object to make it text?  I'll start googling, but if you could reply, that would be great.

Comment: Shay, figured it out based on your answer to someone else on another site.  Changed the last line to:

} | Select-Object Name,Id,ResolutionPath,@{n="Endpoints";e={[string]::join(";",$_.Endpoints)}}

Thank you again!

Comment: @Bill Excellent, that's what I was just going to write with one update, in v2 you can use the -join operator: @{n="Endpoints";e={$_.Endpoints -join ';'}}

Comment: @JPBlanc yes, I am hard coding fields but in my tests I had no issues with multiple Urls (endpoints).

Answer (score 3):

with PowerShell 5 you can use the fabulous command 'convertfrom-string'

```
$template=@'
Service name: {ServiceName*:SearchService} 
Service ID: {serviceID:393234543546} 
Service resolution path: {ServicePath:/ProxyServices/SearchService} 
Serivce endpoints:
http://{ServiceEP*:servername.company.com:13010/Services/SearchService_5_0}
http://{ServiceEP*:servername2.tcompany.tcom:13011/testServices/SearchService_45_0}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Service name: {ServiceName*:Worker} 
Service ID: {serviceID:14187898547} 
Service resolution path: {ServicePath:/ProxyServices/Worker} 
Serivce endpoints:
http://{ServiceEP*:servername3.company.com:13010/Services/SearchService}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Service name: {ServiceName*:WSDL} 
Service ID: {serviceID:14234321885} 
Service resolution path: {ServicePath:/gman/wsdlUpdte} 
Serivce endpoints:
http://{ServiceEP*:servername4.company.com:13010/Services/SearchService_5_0}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'@


#explode file with template
$listexploded=Get-Content -Path "c:\temp\file1.txt" | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template

#export csv 
$listexploded |select *, @{N="ServiceEP";E={$_.ServiceEP.Value -join ","}} -ExcludeProperty ServiceEP | Export-Csv -Path "C:\temp\res.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Will this work with any number of ServiceEP? Or would I need to create a template for one with more than 2 entries?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Get-Content | ? { $_ -match ': ' } | % { $_ -split ': ' } | Export-Csv Test.csv;
```

Basically it boils down to:

1. Get all text content as an array
2. Filter for lines that contain ': '
3. For each line left over, split it on ': '
4. Export object arrays to a CSV file named *test.csv*

Hope this points you in the right direction.

Note: Code is untested.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general way parsing files with records and records of records (and so on), it use the powerfull PowerShell `switch` instruction with regular expressions and the begin(), Process(), end() function template.

Load it, debug it, correct it ...

```
function Parse-Text
{
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param
  (
    [Parameter(mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [string]$ficIn,
    [Parameter(mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$false)]
    [string]$ficOut
  )

  begin
  {
    $svcNumber = 0
    $urlnum = 0
    $Service = @()
    $Service += @{}
  } 

  Process 
  {
    switch -regex -file $ficIn
    {
      # End of a service
      "^-+"
      {
        $svcNumber +=1
        $urlnum = 0
        $Service += @{}
      }
      # URL, n ones can exist
      "(http://.+)" 
      {
        $urlnum += 1
        $url = $matches[1]
        $Service[$svcNumber]["Url$urlnum"] = $url
      }
      # Fields
      "(.+) (.+): (.+)" 
      {
        $name,$value = $matches[2,3]
        $Service[$svcNumber][$name] = $value
      }
    }
  }

  end 
  {
    #$service[3..0] | % {New-Object -Property $_ -TypeName psobject} | Export-Csv c:\Temp\ws.csv
    # Get all the services except the last one (empty -> the file2Parse is teerminated by ----...----)
    $tmp = $service[0..($service.count-2)] | Sort-Object @{Expression={$_.keys.count };Descending=$true}
    $tmp | % {New-Object -Property $_ -TypeName psobject} | Export-Csv $ficOut
  }
}


Clear-Host
Parse-Text -ficIn "c:\Développements\Pgdvlp_Powershell\Apprentissage\data\Text2Parse.txt" -ficOut "c:\Temp\ws.csc"
cat "c:\Temp\ws.csv"
```