# Reading and Parsing a Strucutred Text File with Powershell

Tags: string, powershell, parsing, string-parsing

I'm trying to read the text files that are generated from another program and parse them to perform other actions.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549411/powershell-parse-a-structured-text-file-and-save-to-csv) topic is close but the file I'm reading has more "structuring" for lack of a better word.  Here is a sample of what the file I am reading will look like for reference:

```
data:extend(
{
{
type = "buildformula",
name = "item1",
active = false,
buildtime = 3,
ingredients =
{
  {"ingredient1", 1},
  {"ingredient2", 4},
  {"ingredient3", 5}
},
result = "finished item 1"
},        

{
type = "buildformula",
name = "item2",
active = true,
buildtime = 12,
ingredients =
{
  {"ingredient1", 2},
  {"ingredient2", 3}
},
result = "finished item 2"
},
}
)
```

One other suggestion in that post referenced ConvertFrom-String command which seems to have the power I need but i'm still getting no results.

Lastly here is the most recent code I have :

```
    $TemplateAdr = @'
{
type = "buildformula",
name = "item1",
active = false,
buildtime = 3,
ingredients =
{
  {"ingredient1", 1},
  {"ingredient2", 4},
  {"ingredient3", 5}
},
result = "finished item 1"
},        

{
type = "buildformula",
name = "item2",
active = true,
buildtime = 12,
ingredients =
{
  {"ingredient1", 2},
  {"ingredient2", 3}
},
result = "finished item 2"
},
'@
$output=Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\itembuilds.txt" |  ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $TemplateAdr
```

I'm new to PowerShell but I feel like this is possible.

Comment: Please, can you give a example of itembuilds.txt.

Comment: The first block is a copy paste from the file of which i'm attempting to read.

Comment: Your data looks like it's [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Example). I'm not too familiar with that, and trying to convert your sample using `ConvertFrom-Json` failed (`Invalid Object pass in`). Any luck using this command with the full file? Do you know if this is meant to be standard JSON?

Comment: @gms0ulman I typed `ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject C:\temp\itembuilds.txt` and got `ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive: C.`

Comment: @gms0ulman Also thanks for turning me onto JSON.  I had not known of that but after reviewing your link it sure looks like that's the intent of the file.  I'll see if I can confirm that and report back.

Comment: @Eleron Hope that leads you to a solution. The command you tried attempts to the the _string_ into json. Try: `Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\itembuilds.txt" |  ConvertFrom-Json`

Comment: @gms0ulman I got `ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive: data.
At line:1 char:46
+ Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\itembuilds.txt" | ConvertFrom-Json
+                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand`

Comment: In the non-sample version of the file there is one line at the top.  I copied sample data when I thought I was dealing with structured strings and missed that line.  Not sure if its relevant to the JSON discussion but I have updated my source with the line and its closing paren.  Apologies on missing that!

Comment: Well, the text that you have posted does not appear to be valid JSON anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$TemplateAdr` template is not marked up as such.

Try this one:

```
$TemplateAdr = @'
data:extend(
\{
\{
type = "{Type*:buildformula}",
name = "{Name:item1}",
active = {[bool]Active:false},
buildtime = {[int]BuildTime:3},
{Ingredients:ingredients =
\{
  \{"{IngredientName*:ingredient1}", {[int]IngredientCount:1}\},
  \{"{IngredientName*:ingredient2}", {[int]IngredientCount:4}\},
  \{"{IngredientName*:ingredient3}", {[int]IngredientCount:5}\}
\},}
result = "{[string]Result:finished item 1}"
\},

\{
type = "{Type*:buildformula}",
name = "{Name:item2}",
active = {[bool]Active:true},
buildtime = {[int]BuildTime:12},
{Ingredients:ingredients =
\{
  \{"{IngredientName*:ingredient1}", {[int]IngredientCount:2}\},
  \{"{IngredientName*:ingredient2}", {[int]IngredientCount:3}\}
\},}
result = "{[string]Result:finished item 2}"
\},
\}
)
'@

Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\itembuilds.txt" |
    ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $TemplateAdr |
        Select-Object -Property Type,Name,Active,BuildTime,@{Name='Ingredients';Expression={$_.Ingredients.Items}}
```

Curly braces are escaped using `\`. I've explicitly specified PowerShell types for some of the properties (You might not want that). I've used `Select-Object` to map `ingredients` list to a new property.

Feel free to change property names inside field specifications (`{PropertyName:whatever}`).