# powershell object create from flat file

Tags: powershell

I have flat file would like to create new PS objects with the 'VirtualServer' as the Name. There will always be 'Destination' but not always 'Pool'/'Node'. Sometimes 'Pool'/'Node' will be more than one.

```
VirtualServer=_1095cservicecenter.yip.com_redirect_vs
 Destination=10.10.67.211%104:80
VirtualServer=aarp.yip.com_443_vs
 Destination=10.10.70.63%107:443
  Pool=aarp.yip.com_443_Pool
    Node=trciis-na1-03-30(10.10.12.30%107)
VirtualServer=aarp.yip.com_redirect_vs
 Destination=10.10.70.63%107:80
VirtualServer=abbviebenefits.yip.com_443_vs
 Destination=10.10.67.87%104:443
   Pool=abbviebenefits.yip.com_2t_443_Pool
    Node=bob-na1-65-82(10.10.6.82%104)
    Node=bob-na1-66-83(10.10.6.83%104)
    Node=bob-na1-67-84(10.10.6.84%104)
    Node=bob-na1-68-90(10.10.6.90%104)
    Node=bob-na1-69-91(10.10.6.91%104)
    Node=bob-na1-70-103(10.10.6.103%104)
    Node=bob-na1-71-108(10.10.6.108%104)
    Node=bob-na1-72-109(10.10.6.109%104)
    Node=bob-na1-73-111(10.10.6.111%104)
```

Must be new objects:

```
VirtualServer=_1095cservicecenter.yip.com_redirect_vs
 Destination=10.10.67.211%104:80


VirtualServer=aarp.yip.com_443_vs
 Destination=10.10.70.63%107:443
  Pool=aarp.yip.com_443_Pool
    Node=trciis-na1-03-30(10.10.12.30%107)

VirtualServer=aarp.yip.com_redirect_vs
 Destination=10.10.70.63%107:80

VirtualServer=abbviebenefits.yip.com_443_vs
 Destination=10.10.67.87%104:443
   Pool=abbviebenefits.yip.com_2t_443_Pool
    Node=bob-na1-65-82(10.10.6.82%104)
    Node=bob-na1-66-83(10.10.6.83%104)
    Node=bob-na1-67-84(10.10.6.84%104)
    Node=bob-na1-68-90(10.10.6.90%104)
    Node=bob-na1-69-91(10.10.6.91%104)
    Node=bob-na1-70-103(10.10.6.103%104)
    Node=bob-na1-71-108(10.10.6.108%104)
    Node=bob-na1-72-109(10.10.6.109%104)
    Node=bob-na1-73-111(10.10.6.111%104)
```

How to create, this not working:

```
$LoadBalancer = "(?<VirtualServer=>\S*)",
   "(?<Destination=>\S*)",
   "(?<Pool=>\S*)",
   "(?<Node=>\S*)" -join "\s+"
```

Comment: How is it not working? Do you get errors? Do you get the wrong data? Do you get no data? How are you loading the file? How are you trying to access the data? All you have shown us is an array that you are joining into a string. What do you then do with that string? Do you use it in a regular expression? Do you print it out and mail it to Santa Claus so he knows what presents to bring you?

Comment: Thank you Santa Claus. If I list "VirtualServer" then I want it give me "Destination" and "Pool" and "Node" with that VirtualServer. So one PS object with this details.

Comment: Please edit your question to add this detail and show actual code. Please show an [MCV](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

You first need to read in the flat file and parse that appropriately and use a combination of the two following commands:

```
$object = New-Object psobject
```

and

```
Add-Member -InputObject $object -MemberType NoteProperty -Name HeaderName -value "Value"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549411/powershell-parse-a-structured-text-file-and-save-to-csv